# fopen creates file like Resource id #3?

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

i am trying yo create a new file using a existing file.

but When i create a new file  in my uploads folder a file is automatically created with **resource id #3** WHY??

```
public function edit_ini_custom($id)
{
    /*Getting parameters name to display in view*/
    $this->data['params'] = $this->parameter_m->get();

    /*Path of our BASE and CUSTOM INI files*/
    $path = "./uploads/"; 

    $this->db->select('*');

    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    /*Here the id is the ID we got from URI View*/

    $this->db->from('base_ini');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->row();

    $filename= $result->base_ini_filename;

    $path= $result->file_path;



    /*Reading Contents from our path and the name of file we got from database*/
    file_get_contents($path.$filename);

    $this->data['parameters'] = parse_ini_file($path.$filename);

    /*Getting Our POST DATA from View*/
        $data = array(
                        'SipUserName' => $this->input->post('SipUserName') , 
                        'SipAuthName' => $this->input->post('SipAuthName'), 
                        'DisplayName' => $this->input->post('DisplayName'),
                        'Password' => $this->input->post('Password'), 
                        'Domain' => $this->input->post('Domain'), 
                        'Proxy' => $this->input->post('Proxy'),
                        'Port' => $this->input->post('Port'), 
                        'ServerMode' => $this->input->post('ServerMode'),
                        'Param_1' => $this->input->post('Param_1'),
                        'Param_2' => $this->input->post('Param_2')
                    );


        $this->load->helper('file');
        $suffix =$this->input->post('SipUserName');

        /*Setting the Name of File*/
        $name =$this->session->userdata('username');

        /*Creating New file with the name of customer loggedin*/
        $file_new = fopen('uploads/'.$name.$suffix.'.ini', 'w');




        fwrite($file_new, "[INIDetails]\n");

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
        {
            fwrite($file_new, "    $key = $value\n");
        }

        fclose($file_new);  

        /*Setting path to New CUSTOM file with customer name as prefix*/
        $file = $path.$file_new;


        function write_php_ini($array, $file)
        {
            $res = array();
            foreach($array as $key => $val)
            {
                if(is_array($val))
                {
                    $res[] = "[$key]";
                    foreach($val as $skey => $sval) $res[] = "$skey = ".(is_numeric($sval) ? $sval : '"'.$sval.'"');
                }
                else $res[] = "$key = ".(is_numeric($val) ? $val : '"'.$val.'"');
            }
            safefilerewrite($file, implode("\r\n", $res));
        }

        function safefilerewrite($fileName, $dataToSave)
        {    if ($fp = fopen($fileName, 'w'))
            {
                $startTime = microtime(TRUE);
                do
                {            $canWrite = flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
                   // If lock not obtained sleep for 0 - 100 milliseconds, to avoid collision and CPU load
                   if(!$canWrite) usleep(round(rand(0, 100)*1000));
                } while ((!$canWrite)and((microtime(TRUE)-$startTime) < 5));

                //file was locked so now we can store information
                if ($canWrite)
                {            fwrite($fp, $dataToSave);
                    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
                }
                fclose($fp);
            }

        }

        /*Creates ini file, dumps array to string and creates .INI file*/
        write_php_ini($data,$file);
        /*Back to you index page id data is submmited*/
        if(isset($_POST['submit'] ))
        {
            redirect('customer/upload_ini/index');
        }

        $this->data['subview'] = 'customer/upload/edit_ini_custom';
        $this->load->view('customer/_layout_main', $this->data);



}
```

Comment: fopen dont return a filename - it returns an resource

Comment: Okay but why does it create a file? should i not be jst creating a temp file?

Comment: `$file_new = fopen('uploads/'.$name.$suffix.'.ini', 'w');` **creates a file**. Then, after that line you are using variable `$file_new` as if it's containing some textual information - it isn't, it holds a pointer to a **resource**. You're trying to use that resource as as string, so PHP tells you what the resource's **name** is. Your code is a huge mess, so it's not clear immediately what you're doing. After you screwed up with `$file_new`, you happily passed it to `write_php_ini` function. Of course you will get weird results..

Comment: @N.B. i know my code is a total mess , but can you please tell me the alogo i should do here. Currently i open an existing file and copy its content to another file and allow the user to edit that file. so that will be a new file